# Hi, I am very new to sails. can anyone help me with understanding how & where to pass sql query for mysql database

Tags: sails.js

I am very new to sails. can anyone help me with understanding how & where to pass sql query for mysql database

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you need to do:

1) Install the adapter `npm install sails-mysql --save`

2) Set up the connection. In the file `config/datastores.js`, there is an object called `default`. This is where you configure your local database. There is a commented out example of how it should look: `adapter: 'sails-mysql', url 'mysql://user:password@host:port/database'`

When you're ready to set up your production db, do the same in `config/env/production.js` under `datastores.default`

3) Set up your models: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models

An easy way to get started is using `sails generate model <ModelName>` in the cli.

4) Next you have a choice: either set up your tables manually in mysql (using mysql workbench or similar) or you can take advantage of sails auto-migrations to set them up automatically. To do this, make sure that in `config/models.js` you have `migrate: 'alter'`. Then the first time you lift use `sails lift --drop`

5) You should now be able to make queries from anywhere in the back end with calls like `var newRecord = async <ModelName>.create({...}}).fetch()`